# How to send arbitrary Class over Android Beam?

Tags: android, nfc

I would like to give my app the ability to share information with each other using NFC Android Beam.  The app transfers a serializable class to exchange information.  Information sent is NOT a "well known" type so I would like to ask what is the correct way of transferring arbitrary classes across the NFC e.g. what is the TNF_? and the RTD_ if any please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The app transfers a serializable class to exchange information

I would not recommend that. First, it makes your app more fragile from a class versioning standpoint. Second, it locks you into Android, and you may want to support other mobile operating systems in the future. I strongly encourage you to use a platform-neutral format (XML, JSON, protobuf, whatever), one where you can embed versioning information into the data being transferred.

> I would like to ask what is the correct way of transferring arbitrary classes across the NFC e.g. what is the TNF_? and the RTD_ if any please?

I would go with `TNF_MIME_MEDIA` and a vendor-specific MIME type.

Comment: Okay thanks.  Also you are absolutely right on the comment about using XML etc.. to exchange data.